# SQL Server analysis service (SSAS) running on domain account - SSMS connection error

Tags: networking, security, sql-server-2016

I have SSAS running on stand alone SQL Server (not clustered). SSAS was originally running under LocalSystem account and things were working fine. I changed SSAS to run as the domain account as part of a project requirement. Once I made this change I can only loggin to SSAS from SSMS on the server. I can't login from any other computer with SSMS. I did try to connect to the port specifically with ServerName:2383 from a remote computer and I still get the errror message, "...no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". I have used netstat /aon to ensure SSAS in running on the default port 2383. I have created rules to allow from the port and the SSAS application. I verified that the "ListenOnlyOnLocalConnections" is set to false. I have restarted the SSAS / Browser service. What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I identified the initial source of my problem. I didn’t use SQL Server Configuration Manager to change the NT Service\MSSQLServerOLA to a domain account for the SSAS service. Instead, I used Services thinking it was basically the same process. Unfortunately the Microsoft documented solution https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/cc917670(v=technet.10) to correct this issue didn’t work for me. I ultimately had to uninstall and reinstall analysis services. This issue seems like it is a SQL Server 2016 Enterprise bug.